# Branch.io setDebug() not working

Tags: android, branch.io, referrals

I have implemented Branch.io referral program.Debug mode is on. When I click on the link it navigates to the app. On signup success i am using setIdentity("user_id") method and then getCredits() and Redeem Credits of referrer and referred user.It works only one or two times on a device then after that, it returns returned{} on setIdentity("user_id").
There is my code:

```
                      branch.setIdentity(Settings.USERID, new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                                    if (!referrer_id.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                                        branch.userCompletedAction("referAFriend");
                                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {

                                                branch.loadRewards(new Branch.BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {

                                                        if (error == null) {
                                                            if (changed) {
                                                                credits = branch.getCredits();

                                                                Log.e("credits", credits + "");

                                                                branch.redeemRewards(credits, new Branch.BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {

                                                                        branch.logout(new Branch.LogoutStatusListener() {
                                                                            @Override
                                                                            public void onLogoutFinished(boolean loggedOut, BranchError error) {
                                                                                if (loggedOut) {

                                                                                    Log.e("210", loggedOut + "");
                                                                                    if (!referrer_id.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                                                          Log.e("209",referrer_id+"");

                                                                                        branch.setIdentity(referrer_id, new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
                                                                                            @Override
                                                                                            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                                                                                                Log.e("215",referringParams+"");
                                                                                                if(referringParams.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("{}"))
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    Utils.resultdialog(SignupActivity.this, "Registered Successfully.", "signup");

                                                                                                }
                                                                                                else {
                                                                                                    if (error == null) {
                                                                                                        branch.loadRewards(new Branch.BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
                                                                                                            @Override
                                                                                                            public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {
                                                                                                                if (error == null) {
                                                                                                                    if (changed) {

                                                                                                                        refreepoints = branch.getCredits();
                                                                                                                        Log.e("refreepoints", refreepoints + "");


                                                                                                                        branch.redeemRewards(refreepoints, new Branch.BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
                                                                                                                            @Override
                                                                                                                            public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {
                                                                                                                                if (error == null) {
                                                                                                                                    if (changed) {

                                                                                                                                        } else {

                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                    } else {
                                                                                                                                        Log.e("255", "255");


                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                        });
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                } else {
                                                                                                                    Log.e("265", error + "");
                                                                                                                    Utils.resultdialog(SignupActivity.this, "Registered Successfully.", "signup");

                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                        });
                                                                                                    } else {
                                                                                                        Log.e("268", error + "");


                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        });
                                                                                    } else {
                                                                                        Log.e("266", "error");


                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        });


                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                            } else {
                                                                Log.e("271", error + "");


                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            Log.e("274", error + "");


                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });


                                            }
                                        }, 10000);
                                    } else {

                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Amruta from Branch here: Although, I am not sure of what you wish to achieve with the above code snippet as I see you logging out your user and immediately logging him back in, when I tested with the above snippet in my Sample app multiple times, it worked correctly every single time. The setIdentity call always returned in following format:
{"session_id":sid, "identity_id":identityId,"referring_data":"<Branch link params>"}


If you continue to face issues, could you please write in to `integrations@branch.io`?

Comment: is your app available on the Play Store where I could recreate the issue you are facing?

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh my app is not available on play store.

Comment: Could you either write to `integrations@branch.io` or post it on Github [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/issues)